# Deserializing JSON string with unescaped double quotes

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

How do I deserialize JSON that has unescaped double quotes in C#?

JSON string example:

```
{
 "Id": "4c8e6419-f094-48a0-94f8-752ccd7f0354",
 "Description": "Anastasia Sfeir is a Mexican actress, singer, and model. She is best known for her roles in the telenovelas "La que no podia amar" and "Lo que la vida me robo"."
}
```

the JSON string exactly looks like this:

```
string json = "\n{\n \"Id\": \"78d4f53a-8614-4096-ace9-72a62dbcdbc3\",\n \"Description\": \"100 Thieves is an esports organization and lifestyle brand founded in 2016 by Matthew \"Nadeshot\" Haag.\"\n}\n";
```

I'm getting exceptions, but once I removed the quotes, it worked.

```
result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Description>(response);
```

I have no control over the response, so I hope there is an easy built-in way to handle this.

Comment: "How do I deserialize such JSON" - it's not JSON, if it's actually as you've shown it. That's why you're getting an exception. I would frankly be pretty worried by any data provider who can't produce valid JSON - it would make me worry about what they might be doing in anything less trivial. While you *could* try to munge this into valid JSON, you're likely to be fighting a losing battle - as soon as you've "fixed" one problem, you're likely to find there's another.

Comment: That is an invalid JSON - check out it yourself using some  online validator.

Comment: the json string exactly looks like this: string json = "\n{\n \"Id\": \"78d4f53a-8614-4096-ace9-72a62dbcdbc3\",\n \"Description\": \"100 Thieves is an esports organization and lifestyle brand founded in 2016 by Matthew \"Nadeshot\" Haag.\"\n}\n";

Comment: @bobmason yes, it is invalid JSON (still). It should be fixed on the sending side.

Comment: You could clone Newtonsoft.Json project from Github, and modify `JsonTextReader.ReadStringIntoBuffer` https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs to fit your mangled JSON. I'm not sure how you propose to handle a piece of text that contains an embedded unescaped quote `"` followed by (possibly whitespace and) either a `,` or a `}` as there is no way of differentiating that from a normal end of string.

Comment: This response is from AI chatbot, most of the time it's fine, but sometimes it's like this.

Comment: @bobmason: Then you should contact the provider and let them know that they're producing invalid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The example JSON payload you provided doesn't have double quotes. Quotes inside of a JSON string are escaped with a backslash (eg: \"). If your string example is exactly how the website is returning it, then that is not valid JSON and cannot be read by a regular JSON parsing library.

If the example string had escaped quotes, it would work fine without any modifications. The issue is with the string you're trying to parse.|

Example of valid JSON with escaped quotation marks:

```
{
 "Id": "4c8e6419-f094-48a0-94f8-752ccd7f0354",
 "Description": "Anastasia Sfeir is a Mexican actress, singer, and model. She is best known for her roles in the telenovelas \"La que no podia amar\" and \"Lo que la vida me robo\"."
}
```

Comment: the json string exactly looks like this: string json = "\n{\n  \"Id\": \"78d4f53a-8614-4096-ace9-72a62dbcdbc3\",\n  \"Description\": \"100 Thieves is an esports organization and lifestyle brand founded in 2016 by Matthew \"Nadeshot\" Haag.\"\n}\n";

Comment: @bobmason: Well, that's "the string with C# escapes". The backslashes aren't actually in the string. (It's important to understand the difference between what the string contains, and how the VS debugger displays it.) As everyone has said: it's invalid JSON.

Comment: @bobmason an easy solution if the AI chatbot you are using is producing invalid JSON is to include "use ' instead of " for quotation marks" in your AI chat query. Not the most optimal solution but it'll work and will make it stop producing JSON with improperly serialized quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

if all your json strings are have only 2 properties Id and Description, you can try to fix your json string using this code

```
var desc = "\"Description\":";
var firstIndex = json.IndexOf(desc) + desc.Length + 1;
var lastIndex=json.LastIndexOf("\"") + 1;
        
json = json.Replace( json[firstIndex..lastIndex],JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json[(firstIndex+1)..(lastIndex-1)]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use postman to call the API manually first, and see if the response is valid.

Another issue is `the JSON string exactly looks like this:`. How did you see the json string? Through debugger?

`I'm getting exceptions` - what exceptions? Provide debug detail.

How did you get the HttpResponse? And how did you read it into a string? Provide codes, so we can help you.

Comment: This response is from AI chatbot, most of the time it's fine, but sometimes it's like this.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Serge answer, I devised this method to clean the description.
Since this JSON is a reply from an AI chatbot, so sometimes it's not 100% correct, which will cause a loss of money for the tokens used...

```
     static string FixAndDeserializeJson(string json)
        {
            try
            {
                // Extract the 'Description' value using a regular expression.
                var descriptionPattern = @"""Description"":\s*""(.*?)""";
                var match = Regex.Match(json, descriptionPattern);

                if (match.Success)
                {
                    // Get the matched group which contains the description
                    var descriptionValue = match.Groups[1].Value;

                    // Decode Unicode characters and remove backslashes and quotes
                    var fixedDescription = DecodeEncodedNonAsciiCharacters(descriptionValue)
                        .Replace("\\", "").Replace("\"", "");

                    // Replace the old description with the fixed one in the original JSON string
                    var fixedJson = Regex.Replace(json, descriptionPattern, $"\"Description\": \"{fixedDescription}\"");

                    // Validate the fixed JSON by attempting to parse it.
                    JToken.Parse(fixedJson);

                    // If parsing is successful, return the fixed JSON
                    return fixedJson;
                }
                else
                {
                    // If the description isn't found, the JSON is likely invalid or not in the expected format
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // If parsing throws an exception at any point, the JSON is invalid; return null
                return null;
            }
        }


        static string DecodeEncodedNonAsciiCharacters(string value)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(
                value,
                @"\\u(?<Value>[a-fA-F0-9]{4})",
                m => {
                    return ((char)int.Parse(m.Groups["Value"].Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString();
                });
        }
```